# Prevent NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification event to overlap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsnotifications

Ok I have a very tricky problem that I spent days to understand and know I'm not sure how to fix it.

I have a CoreData database updated from different thread with different context. My problem is that sometimes NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification event overlap and create corruption of the base that lead to crash. Here is an example:

```
Thread                   Main                                          NSFetchResultsController

Update database
Save database           NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification1
                        merge                                          delegate process 1
                                                                       process 1 done

Update database
Save database           NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification2
                        merge                                          delegate process 2
                                                                       process 2 done
Update database
Save database           NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification3
                        merge                                          delegate process 3

Update database
Save database           NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification4
                        merge          

                                                                       process 3 done
                                                                       delegate process 4
                                                                       CRASH
                                                                       process 4 done
```

In this pseudo code example process1 and process2 works without problem
but sometimes the main thread receives overlapping update event and the
you have process4 starting to read the database before process3 is done.

Is there an official way to deal with that ? Does CoreData offers a solution
to this situation or do I have to use NSLock ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the portion of your code that processes the merge notification? Without that, I don't think there's much more anyone will be able to deduce. As I said in my answer, the contexts lock the persistent store coordinator to serialise access, which should prevent these kind of issues.

Answer (score 2):

The contexts should be locking the persistent store coordinator that they share to prevent these issues.

If process 3 and process 4 are running on the main thread, then how can 4 start before 3 is finished? Don't forget that notifications are received on the thread that posts them, so you need explicitly execute your code to merge the changes on the main thread (apologies if I'm stating the obvious).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my question as I turns out this is even more complicated since there is a NSFetchResultsController involved. Somehow the database is sometimes updated when NSFetchResultsControllerDelegate is processing the last update and this causes troubles

Comment: I think the controller and its delegate are a red herring though. That activity should be taking place on the main thread. Crashes like this are almost always because a context is used from a thread other than the one that created it.